# Mongo dynamic collection creation and locking

Tags: mongodb

I am working on an app where I am looking into creating MongoDB collections on the fly as they are needed.

The app consumes data from a data source and maps the data to a collection. If the collection does not exist, the app:

- creates the collection
- kicks off appropriate indexes in the background
- shards the collection
  and then inserts the data into the collection.

While this is going on, other processes will be reading and writing from the database.

Looking at this MongodDB locking [FAQ](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use-), it appears that the reads and writes in other collections of the database should not be affected by the dynamic collection creation snd setup i.e. they won't end up waiting on a lock we acquired to create the collection.

Question: Is the above assumption correct?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you insert into a collection which does not exist, then a new collection is created automatically. Of course, this new collection does not have any index (apart from `_id`) and is not sharded.

So, you must ensure the collection is created before the application starts any inserts.

However, it is no problem to create indexes and enable sharding on a collection which contains already some data.

Note, when you enable sharding on an empty collection or a collection with low amount of data, then all data is written initially to the primary shard. You may use [sh.splitAt()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.splitAt/) to  pre-split the upcoming data.

Comment: just to double confirm :) sharding the collection is not going to cause Mongo to take an exclusive lock on the entire database?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe try. Maybe it locks the collection, certainly not the entire database.